# How does Flame support Rive animation?

Tags: flutter, dart, flame, rive

It's mentioned [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flame) under [goals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gv5p.png) that [flame](https://flame-engine.org/) has basic [Rive](https://rive.app) support. I'm guessing it needs to be rendered on the flame canvas.

Are there any relevant examples or tutorials which could give a basic idea as to how to use a one-shot rive animation in a game made with flutter using the Flame engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a goal that is not fulfilled yet.

Currently we only have Flare support (the old Rive) with [this bridge library](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame_flare).
Once we start implementing support for it you will see it [here](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame_rive), and once it is done we will move it from there into the [monorepo](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/tree/main/packages) and you'll see `flame_rive` there.